# При компиляции Pyinstaller не подхватывает иконки из соседней папки

Tags: python, компиляция, exe, pyinstaller

Имеется программа, в которой используются иконки из папки, которая находится в папке проекта редактора PyCharm. Пример пути к иконке: "icons/icon.ico". В проекте всё работает как и должно, однако "pyinstaller" при компиляции в 1 файл не подхватывает папку с иконками, из-за чего они не загружаются в программе.

Я так понимаю, что программа ждёт, пока я скину папку с нужными иконками в ту же директорию.

Можно ли это исправить (чтобы "pyinstaller" поглотил иконки внутрь exe файла)?

**UPDATE**

---

Также в программе используются соседние файлы: папка, БД, txt

Comment: какие параметры у PyInstaller при компиляции?

Comment: Только флаг -F. Забыл упомянуть, что в программе используются соседние файлы (папка, БД, txt)

Comment: А у вас иконка берётся в коде или вам надо поставить как иконку exe  файла?

Comment: В самом коде используются, иконку exe файла я знаю, как поставить - флаг -i <путь к иконке>

Comment: А без флага -F работает?

Comment: Мне нужно одним exe'шником

Comment: используете ли вы PyQt ?

Answer (score 0):

В основном коде, где прописываешь иконки, вставь полные пути до иконок. Например:

```py
icon.addPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap("C:\\Users\\User\\Desktop\\test\\TEST.png"), QtGui.QIcon.Normal, QtGui.QIcon.Off)
```